# How many 4 digit numbers end in a 0?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I need to crack a code but all I know about it is that it has four digits and ends in zero.

Comment: In other words, "How many three-digit strings are there?"?

Comment: just count how many 3 digit numbers with significant zeros

Comment: Can it begin with zeros?

Comment: 'Tis a basic counting problem. Use Constructive Counting.

Answer (score 2):

Approach via multiplication principle.

- Pick the first digit.  Since you say 4 digit **numbers**, this implies that the leading digit cannot be a zero, but it can be any of the others.  (*if you allow leading zeroes, this is technically what is called a* **string**, *not a number*).  $\color{blue}{\text{9 options}}$ (*if counting strings, ten options instead*)
- Pick the second digit.  Any of the ten digits are allowed here.  $\color{blue}{\text{10 options}}$
- Pick the third digit.  Any of the ten digits are allowed here.  $\color{blue}{\text{10 options}}$
- Pick the fourth digit.  You say it must end in a zero, so only one option is allowed here.  $\color{blue}{\text{1 option}}$

If *every* possibility is described by *exactly one* sequence of choices for the steps outlined above, then the number of possibilities is the product of the number of choices available at each step.

> In other words, $9\cdot 10\cdot 10\cdot 1 = 900$ options.

Answer (score 1):

This is clearly equal to the number of $3$ digit numbers (just add $0$ at the end).

The $3$ digit numbers go from $100$ to $999$ so they are $999-100+1=900$